# Javascript is changing variable that needs only to be referenced

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

I'm pulling some data from a reference object changing it around for what I need, but for some reason my code is also changing the object i'm referencing..

```
var obj = {name:"list of things", list:[{name:"thing", 1},{name:"other thing", 2}]};
function doStuff () {
    var ref = obj;
    for(var p=0;p<ref.list.length;p++){
        ref.list.splice(1,1);
    }
    return ref;
}
```

For some reason where I'm using this structure in my code, its changing 'obj' as well as 'ref'. can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 2):

The `obj` in your example is not an object, it is a reference to an object that lives somewhere in memory. This is why when you do `ref=obj`, you get another reference to the same object, so changing the object `ref` references is the same as changing the object `obj` references.

What you want to do is clone your object, so you end up with two different objects. There are some good answers regarding cloning on StackOverflow and the whole web for that matter. Feel free to use any of those.

Comment: I wouldn't say "popular belief" as those who know how it works actually know how it works.  More like "common mistake".

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript assignes by reference.  You would need to do a deep copy in order to clone an object.

See: http://webdevwonders.com/deep-copy-javascript-objects/